# Expandable list view design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I would like to design a layout similar to the attached image.
Specifically, I need to have something like **"Repeat"** *Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri*. Is it a snipper, expandable listview?

What is the name of that view and how can I implement it?

[image]?

Comment: i think it is a spinner. did you try to inspect it with hierarchyviewer ?

Comment: Spinner has different shape. The arrow shapes are different. What is hierarchyviewr? Where can I find it?

Comment: hierarchyviewer is in the android tool kit, and google is your friend

Comment: Hierarchyviewer did not help me. Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This layout is implemented using preferences.

Read this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)